# word interop / adding new field to footer deletes existing fields

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I've been using interop to edit existing word documents. My problem is; i need to add a new field to document footer and that, to my suprise, deletes existing footer fields, so only the newly added field remains. There is no clear documentation about it and the result is rather unexpected. Below is my code:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section wordSection in wordDocument.Sections)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeadersFooters footers = wordSection.Footers;
            foreach (HeaderFooter footer in footers)
            {
                footer.Range.Select();
                Field f = appWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(appWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range);
                appWord.Selection.TypeText(footerText);
            }
        }
```

Comment: OK, I think it would help if you could provide a sample of what an existing footer contained, and what you want it to look like. For example, suppose your existing footer contains the text "myexistingfooter" at the left hand side of your footer. What should be in your footer?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is expected behaviour, because ".Add" is not ".Append" or ".InsertAfter", where you might reasonably hope that the field would be tacked onto the end of the selection. If you select a piece of text in Word and issue the VBA command

```
Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range
```

you will see much the same thing.

WHat you need to do is establish the precise range where you need to insert your field, and add it there. Ideally, avoid use of Selection altogether. So if you need the field to come at the beginning of the footer, you could start with the following VBA sample and translate it into C# (sorry, I don't have the energy right now).

```
Sub insertFieldAtStartOfSec1Footers()
Dim footer As HeaderFooter
Dim rng As Word.Range
For Each footer In ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers
  Set rng = footer.Range
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  ' Insert a simple SECTION field 
  rng.Fields.Add rng, WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, "SECTION", False
  Set rng = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Field` part is not even necessary. `footer.Range.Text = footer.Range.Text + "New Text";` or `footer.Range.InsertAfter("New Text");` would be enough (was writing my own answer, but your is basically the same, so... +1 :)).

Comment: @varocarbas - the Field part is one of two main options if you want to insert a field, rather than just a piece of text. But not sure whether the .typetext() line in the OP's question is what the OP really wants to do, or just some kind of artefact (e.g. test code) :-)

Comment: Yes, I know that his intention is adding a field; although, from his code it seemed to me that a simple text-adding was enough (actually, this is what the code is doing: creating the Field but then ignoring it and just adding text; although without respecting the existing one). That's why my suggestion (more focused on the true intention than in the actual code/request... never really liked Fields).

Comment: @bibadia i realized that about the range class. But when i try your code i get "Error! Bookmark not defined" in my word file. I use: `object direction = WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;  r.Collapse(direction);
                    Field f = r.Fields.Add(r, WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, footerText); `

Comment: @varocarbas what i want is to have two separate fields, one aligned to center and the other one to the left. I tried both Field and TypeText but there was no difference.

Comment: @ufux: that's probably because wdfieldtype.wdfieldempty inserts a field with nothing but the text you supply in footertext. If footertext does not contain the name of a bookmark, you will see the error you describe, at least until you create the bookmark and update the value of the field you inserted. If you meant to create another type of field, that's a different story.

Comment: @ufux Sorry, not too experienced on Fields, I thought that you wanted to update the Footer text (and the fields bit was misleading you). In any case, what you want (location and alignment) is not intrinsic to fields, but to the ranges where they are located (equivalent to text cannot be aligned, but the corresponding range). A quick and easy way to locate elements and account for different alignments is adding a table. In any case, your code seems pretty far away from what you want: just for what you are doing, it seems that dealing with simple ranges (or even bookmarks) would do the job.

Comment: @both: please see my comment to the original question.

Comment: you are right about fields, that lost me some time because  i presumed that was the way to align to different text blocks. @bibadia I used InsertBefore successfully to insert text just before the existing page number footer but what i need is to have to text blocks one aligned to the left of the footer and page number block is already aligned to the center. How should i go about doing that, maybe creating a new range object instead of using InsertBefore ?

Comment: @ufux: In heders/footers, the alignment is typically done using the standard tabs that are defined for the Header and Footer paragraph styles. i.e. text before the first tab will be left-aligned, text immediately after the first tab will be centred, and text after the second tab will be right-aligned. So you could consider inserting a tab character at the end of the text you insert using InsertBefore. But that assumes that the existing header has been formatted in the standard way using the standard styles. If you cannot guarantee that, you will need to impose your own layout.

Comment: @bibadia your suggestion will probably work, but it seems there is already a tab character before page number field and an additional one pushes it to further right. Is there a way to find that "tab character"'s range so I can call InsertBefore with that Range?

Comment: @ufux: I think you need to think through each case that can occur, and write the code necessary to deal with that case. If the footer _might_  or _might not_ contain a tab, it is up to your code either to detect that situation and deal with it, or for your code to workaround the problem and "start again" (e.g. remove all tabs, and start from that). This is standard programming stuff: if you haven't worked with the Word object model before, you will need to spend some time looking at the members of the Range object.

Comment: @bibadia thanks for your replies, it helped a lot but that pedantry in your last comment was unwarranted, i think. i didn't ask about any programming logic help, just referential information which is hard to get on microsoft's reference docs. I'll figure it out.

Comment: This has been an interesting discussion, and may relate to my question about adding a field to a footer disabling an existing page numbering.  If anyone could check it out an let me know what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866047/ms-word-vba-adding-document-property-field-to-footer-removes-existing-page-n