# Adding document property field to footer removes existing page numbering

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am tying to stamp a document variable field in the footer of every page in a document.  I have figured out how to add the field. However, in doing so, the page numbering field that already exists in the footer becomes disabled, leaving only the text and no longer acting as a dynamic page number.

Here is my code that adds the field, but disables the page numbers somehow. (the "sectionFooter.Range.Text = sectionFooter.Range.Text + " "" line is the only way I could find to even get the page number to still show):

```
For Each docSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    For Each sectionFooter In docSection.Footers
    
            sectionFooter.Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            sectionFooter.Range.Text = sectionFooter.Range.Text + " "
            sectionFooter.Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Dim newPP As Paragraph
            Set newPP = sectionFooter.Range.Paragraphs.Add()
            
            newPP.Range.Font.Size = 8
            newPP.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
            ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=newPP.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DOCVARIABLE  ndGeneratedStamp", preserveformatting:=False
            
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is how you want the new field positioned, then try something like this ...

```
Dim docSection As word.Section, sectionFooter As word.HeaderFooter
Dim rng As word.Range
For Each docSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    For Each sectionFooter In docSection.Footers
        Set rng = sectionFooter.Range
        rng.InsertParagraphAfter
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rng.Font.Size = 8
        rng.Font.Name = "Arial"
        rng.Fields.Add Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DOCVARIABLE  ndGeneratedStamp", PreserveFormatting:=False
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you!  The "InsertParagraphAfter" was the key!

One thing, though - the font did not apply using this as provided.  I have added another answer with full font handling.

Answer (score 0):

Rich's answer handled the heavy lifting, but for anyone who happens upon this, wanted to spell out how I was also able to isolate the new paragraph and apply the font.

```
Set rng = sectionFooter.Range

            rng.InsertParagraphAfter
            Set rng = sectionFooter.Range
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Set newPP = rng.Paragraphs.Last
            newPP.Range.Font.Size = 8
            newPP.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
            rng.Fields.Add Range:=newPP.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DOCVARIABLE  ndGeneratedStamp", preserveformatting:=False
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, we can just remove the commented code too.

**Note** If we use this way, we need to set the page-number first then run the Macro.

```
Dim docSection As Word.Section, sectionFooter As Word.HeaderFooter 
For Each docSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    For Each sectionFooter In docSection.Footers
            'sectionFooter.Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            'sectionFooter.Range.Text = sectionFooter.Range.Text + " "
            sectionFooter.Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Dim newPP As Paragraph
            Set newPP = sectionFooter.Range.Paragraphs.Add()

            newPP.Range.Font.Size = 8
            newPP.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
            ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=newPP.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DOCVARIABLE  ndGeneratedStamp", preserveformatting:=False

    Next
Next
```

Comment: I thought this would work as well :)  However, it eliminates the existing footer fields.  The template I have been using has  different first page footer, with a page number on it, and this disappears when I run the macro as you have it.

Comment: So we also need to try different solution to meet your requirement.